# How to filter two time periods in a year?

Tags: google-earth-engine, datetime

Well, if I want filter to two time periods in a year. Just like 1989-01-01~1989-04-01 and 1989-10-01~1990-01-01.It is about the time series analysis.
There is part of my code, something not shows under ( such as ' rmL457Cloud ' )

```
var landsat2 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_SR')
                        .filterDate('1987-01-01','1987-4-01')
                        .filterBounds(roi)
                        .map(rmL457Cloud)
                        .filter(ee.Filter.lte('CLOUD_COVER',5))
                        .map(scaleImage)
                        .map(NDWI)
                        .map(MNDWI)
                        .mosaic()
                        .clip(roi);
```

Comment: What is the error you are receiving?

Comment: I want to filter two time periods at the same time. But I don't how to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.filter(ee.Filter.or(filter1, filter2))` instead of `.filterDate()`:

```js
var l2 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_SR')
          .filter(ee.Filter.or(
            ee.Filter.date('1989-01-01', '1989-04-01'),
            ee.Filter.date('1989-10-01', '1990-01-01'))
          );
          // .filterBounds()...
```